# How do I restrict access by IP address to my Elasticsearch deployment on the IBM Cloud?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, security, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

I have a number of Elasticsearch deployments on the IBM Cloud and I want to restrict access to those resources only to users who come via certain IP addresses of our business locations.
What is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

IBM Cloud Databases now implements Context Based Restrictions (CBR), which allow you to restrict access to resources based on contexts that include IP addresses.

You can do this with the IBM Command Line Interface (CLI).

You can install the CLI [from here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli) and you will need to add the CBR plugin with:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cbr
```

Log into the IBM Cloud CLI with:

```
ibmcloud login --sso
```

Follow the on-screen instructions to log in.

With CBR, the first step is to define a `zone`, which includes the list of IP address you want to either include or exclude. In this example we will create a zone with a list of included IP addresses. You create the zone by typing:

```
ibmcloud cbr zone-create --name myZone --description "Elastic zone" --addresses 82.11.51.321                                                       
...
OK
                         
id                    4efe2a60974931fb7a7010b72wsxc4bced   
....
```

The next step is to create a `Rule` that binds the zone to the resources you want to restrict access to. In this case we are going to restrict access to the API traffic of all Elasticsearch deployments. You will need the Zone id value from the previous step.

```
ibmcloud cbr rule-create --enforcement-mode enabled \
   --context-attributes "networkZoneId=4efe2a60974931fb7a7010b72wsxc4bced" \
   --service-name databases-for-elasticsearch \
   --api-types crn:v1:bluemix:public:context-based-restrictions::::api-type:data-plane \
   --description "ES Rule"

OK
                         
id                    d63db5581eebb466d4273adb8e531ece   
...  
enforcement_mode      enabled
```

The rule is now created and enabled. Any API traffic that does not originate from IP addresses in the Zone list, will be blocked.

There is more information about different contexts and how to delete and modify rules and zones in the [IBM Cloud Databases documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-databases?topic=cloud-databases-cbr&interface=cli#rules-cli)